# How can I open '_mysql.pyd' in 'D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages'?

Tags: python, mysql

My IDE is 'ulipad', and when I open the file, it can't be shown. How can I get it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this question.
The `.pyd` file will be a DLL so you cannot just *edit* it. Check http://effbot.org/pyfaq/is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll.htm for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.pyd files are DLLs.  You can't usefully open them in text editors.

Comment: well, you can but they're binary so it doesn't help at all :)

Comment: That's why I said "usefully".